# javascript replace text in all form fields on submit

Tags: javascript, forms, replace, onsubmit

I've done some Googling but haven't been able to get this working. What I need to do is look through all of the TEXT fields in my form and replace all instances of "," (comma) with " & # 4 4 ;" (escaped comma) on submit.

Here is the form tag:

```
<form name="buildcourse" id="buildcourse" action="target.htm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="validateForm()">
```

And here is my javascript function:

```
<script language="javascript">
function validateForm(buildcourse){
    $('form input[type="text"]').each(function(){
        this.value = replace(",","&#44;");
    });
}
</script>
```

Would love help to get it working. Sorry I am totally Javascript-inept.

Comment: What is the purpose? This kind of thing is usually best done server side..

Comment: Agreed 100%. In this case it's a legacy ColdFusion site that has many form fields being submitted with the same names and then split apart later on. But that means none of the fields can have commas in them. It's super dumb and annoying, but I just have to get it working and hope we can recode it soon.

Comment: `replace()` belong to `String`, so you have to call it in this manner `String.replace('/,/g' , '&#44;')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this to split at the `commas` then rejoin with `"&#44;"`

```
$('form input[type="text"]').each(function(){
    this.value = this.value.split(',').join('&#44;')
});
```

Pure javascript http://jsfiddle.net/mQrLS/3/

```
var theInputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');  
for (var i = 0; i < theInputs.length; i++) {
    var node = theInputs [i];

    if (node.getAttribute('type') == 'text') {
        // using split
        //node.value = this.value.split(',').join('&#44;');
        // using regex
        node.value= node.value.replace(/,/g,'&#44;');
    }
}
```

As @Radu mentioned the replace with regex does perform faster

Comment: The validation/replacement just doesn't even seem to be getting done, either with your code or mine. Is there a syntax problem I'm overlooking elsewhere?

Comment: I actually just updated my code.  I forgot this.value.split earlier

Comment: Not that it matters much, but `.replace()` with regex works faster: http://jsperf.com/regex-vs-split-join

Comment: @Radu True, I was just being lazy and didn't want to look up the regex.  This is a lot easier to understand lol

Comment: @user1316401 I just added one with just javascript

Comment: Thanks, wirey, I was able to get the "pure javascript" version working by wrapping it in a function and calling it onsubmit. You guys are the best, thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your code is that there is no global replace function. It is however available as a method on any string.

```
<form name="buildcourse" id="buildcourse" action="target.htm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

(took out inline event binding)

```
$('#buildcourse').submit(function() {
    $('form input[type="text"]').each(function(){
        this.value = this.value.replace(/,/g, '&#44;');
    });
});​
```

Comment: this should fix it: `.replace('/,/g' , '&#44;')`

Comment: Perfect, thanks. Note to anyone reading since I wasn't aware of this earlier: specifying flags like `.replace(',', '&#44;', 'g')` is non-standard (see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)!

Comment: `replace(/,/g,'&#44;')` should work  It won't work with quotes around the `/,/g`  http://jsfiddle.net/mQrLS/1/

Comment: @user1316401 He just updated his too.  Both his and mines should work as expected.  Just make sure you are using our updated ones as tested in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mQrLS/2/

Comment: Yes, I thought you were already using jQuery since you had it in your code.  I just used your coded to modify it to work as you wanted.  Do you want a vanilla javascript answer?